# Create a drop area for a rectangle with Kinetic.js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

Im creating a "word" game, the objective is drag a character (a rectangle), into the correct word space (another rectangle), if the user drop a character at a wrong space, the character will return to the original point.

During the drag move, i want to detect if the object is over a word space to contrast it. And if the user drop it, insert the character at the correct place...

How can i detect if the user is dropping the character at the correct place? Collision Detect?
Have it any event to detect if an object is over other object?

I need just the guide lines to detect it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe what you want is the `getIntersections()` method ([docs](http://kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Container.php#getIntersections)), it will return the shapes underneath a specific point.

You could use this to build your own collision detection, i.e., call `getIntersections()` on each corner of the character rectangle and see what shapes you hit.

Comment: bde is correct, this is the best way to go about this for now.  I would like to note, however, that KineticJS will support true collision detection soon.